# Hide disabled button using css

Tags: css

I am trying to hide "left-arrow" when it is disabled. However i can't seem to get the CSS right.

```
[data-tour-elem="left-arrow"] {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images as code, please copy and paste code blocks instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it wrong. You have to use the `:` selector, not `.`.

```css
button {
  border: 5px solid lime;
}

button:disabled {
  border: 5px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<button>
  Not disabled
</button>

<button disabled>
  Disabled
</button>

<button onclick="this.disabled = true;">
   Click to disable
</button>
```

This code gives the active buttons a lime border, and the disabled ones an aqua border.

You can learn more about CSS selectors: [MDN CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) [MDN disabled selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) [DevDocs disabled selector](https://devdocs.io/css/:disabled)